# create_tag() fails in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create AWS snapshot using Boto3 and its failing by all know n options to me.

```
connection=ec2.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-1')
def Create_Snapshot(Source_volID):
    snapshot = connection.create_snapshot(Source_volID)
    while snapshot.status != 'completed':
        snapshot.update()
        print snapshot.status
        time.sleep(5)
        if snapshot.status == 'completed':
            connection.create_tags(Resources=[snapshot.id], Tags=[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'uat3-gold-'}])
            return snapshot.id
```

This returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 62, in <module>
print Create_Snapshot(Source_volID)
File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 47, in Create_Snapshot
connection.create_tags(Resources=[snapshot.id], Tags=[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'uat3-sogpet-gold-'}])
TypeError: create_tags() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Resources'
```

Also tried in other way mentioned in stackoverflow.

```
def Create_Snapshot(Source_volID):
    snapshot = connection.create_snapshot(
    VolumeId=Source_volID,
    Description='Gold volume copy',
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'uat3-gold-'
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
    )
    while snapshot.status != 'completed':
        snapshot.update()
        print snapshot.status
        time.sleep(5)
        if snapshot.status == 'completed':
            connection.create_tags(Resources=[snapshot.id], Tags=[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'uat3-sogpet-gold-'}])
            return snapshot.id
```

Causes error:

```
Number of snaps 0
No Snapshots present within 10 minutes
vol-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 76, in <module>
print Create_Snapshot(Source_volID)
File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 50, in 
Create_Snapshot
'Value': 'uat3-gold-'
TypeError: create_snapshot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'VolumeId'
```

I tried in python3 also but it fails. Please give a clue as I am stuck with this for two days. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide `snapshot.id` value from first piece of code

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile, region_name=region)
client = session.client('ec2')
client.create_snapshot(
    Description='Gold volume copy',
    VolumeId=Source_volID,
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'snapshot',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'Name',
                    'Value': 'uat3-gold-'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Hi Dawid, I got the below exception.                                                                                          Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 71, in <module>
    print Create_Snapshot(Source_volID)
  File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 52, in Create_Snapshot
    'Value': 'uat3-gold-'
TypeError: create_snapshot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'VolumeId'

Comment: What is the value of `Source_volID`?

Comment: def Get_Volume_ID(GoldInstnaceId):
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
    instance = ec2.Instance('i-xxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    volumes = instance.volumes.all()
    for volume in volumes:
        if volume.size == 300:
            return (volume.id)                           This Function gives the volume ID.   If you see the full output its as below.   Number of snaps 0
No Snapshots present within 10 minutes
vol-09d372a98b2ba6fe4
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: It still did not answer my question, please print `Source_volID` at the beginning of `def Create_Snapshot(Source_volID):`

Comment: Printed the variable.                         py-projects>python /Users/brijeshbolar/py-projects/8.py
Number of snaps 0
No Snapshots present within 10 minutes
vol-09d372a98b2ba6fe4
Source_volID is vol-09d372a98b2ba6fe4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 72, in <module>
    print Create_Snapshot(Source_volID)
  File "/Users/py-projects/8.py", line 53, in Create_Snapshot
    'Value': 'uat3-gold-'
TypeError: create_snapshot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'VolumeId'

Comment: `type(Source_volID)` returns str? Please try my code once again as I changed the order of parameters